# Angular 2 - Data binding without needing a component

Tags: angular

I would like to insert a variable or constant into HTML from within the HTML file using Angular 2.

I don't really want to do this by creating a component because it is just for some text in a `<p>` tag.

All I want is this:

```
<p class="text-center vertical-center white">{{some_constant}}</p>
```

It seems trivial but I have done some android development in the past where it is bad practice to hardcode text into a view directly such as into the html. Better practice in Android is when the text is in a constant in a string resource. I would like to know if this type of thing can be achieved with Angular 2.

Could one create a component that is only one html element, such as a `<p>` tag? EG just so that it can be bound to some data?

What are my options?

Comment: I believe the HTML you show needs to be in a Component's template in order for Angular to set up the interpolation data binding.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I think you are right. I have added a component and added a few more html tags to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Binding without a component is not supported in Angular2.
You can use binding within a components template, without adding anything to the class of the component (see below).

**Original**

You can do it this way, if you must:

Add a template variable to a tag, then you can reference it inside the view

```
<span hidden #constants [attr.someConstant]="'someValue'"></span>
<p class="text-center vertical-center white">
  {{constants.getAttribute('someConstant')}}</p>
```

Comment: Does all of that that go straight into the html file? That printed `{{constants.getAttribute('someConstant')}}` onto the web page.

Comment: Yes, all you need to write is in HTML, Angular parses the template with JS of course, there is no way around.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It prints that code onto the web page, instead of just the constant.

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me. It has to be added to the template of an Angular component.